# C3.js: plot categorical time series

Tags: javascript, time-series, visualization, c3.js

I am trying to plot 6 superposed time series created by 3 sensors on 2 machines:

- Sensor 1:

  - Time serie 1 (first machine)
  - Time serie 2 (second machine)
- Sensor 2:

  - Time serie 3 (first machine)
  - Time serie 4 (second machine)
- Sensor 3:

  - Time serie 5 (first machine)
  - Time serie 6 (second machine)

I found that [c3.js](http://c3js.org) is a perfect fit for my need here.

The only (big) problem is that `c3.js` plot only one label by chart [like here](http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html):
[image]

As one can see, `data1 (blue)` correspond to one serie and `data1 (orange)` correspond to one serie, the same thing for `data3 (green)`

**What I need :**

I need the sensors to be my labels => 3 labels and 2 time series by label.

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your need?

Comment: Please tell me what information you need, thank you in advance

Comment: A sample dataset and expected result would be helpful in understanding your need. If you need to simply change the labels data1, data2 etc to your own then that is also possible but i don't think that is what you want.